# Disable weak ciphers of OpenSSL on the server side

Tags: c++, c, security, ssl, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL for my server developed in C.

OpenSSL is called in my source code in the following way:

```
SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void)
{
    SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* load all error messages */
    method = TLSv1_2_server_method();  /* create new server-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* create new context from method */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

int main(int count, char *Argc[])
{   
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    char *portnum;

    // Initialize the SSL library
    SSL_library_init();
    ctx = InitServerCTX();        /* initialize SSL */
    ...
}
```

I tested my server with [ssllabs.com](https://sslabs.com). and I got weaks in the supported ciphers on my server.

[image]

How to disable these weak ciphers in my server?

**---EDIT---**

I tried to add the following line after initiating context

```
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ALL:!NULL-MD5:!NULL-SHA:!NULL-RSA");
```

But nothing change!

Answer (score 4):

For TLS v1.2 and earlier, you can use [`SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list()` or `SSL_set_cipher_list()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html).

For TLS 1.3, you can use [`SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites()` or `SSL_set_ciphersuites()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html).

See [CIPHER LIST FORMAT](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html) for the syntax to use when specifying which ciphers to enable/disable.

Comment: could you please provide example based on the weak ciphers mentioned in the question

Comment: I used this one `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ALL:!NULL-MD5:!NULL-SHA:!NULL-RSA");` but the problem persist